# Visual Studio Code terminal error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, cmder

I have this issue in microsoft visual studio code, whenever I open the terminal the first message I get is `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` The terminal works fine.. just it bugs me to see see this error message whenever I open the terminal.. how do I fix it?

I Installed Cmder as my default visual studio code terminal, maybe there is something related to this error?

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you have installed cmder as the integrated terminal in vscode but in `settings.json` you could try pointing the `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` to `cmd.exe` and the `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows` to what makes `cmd.exe` *be* (act like) cmder which is cmder's `init.bat` file. So in your vscode `settings.json` add or modify the below lines to point to your cmd.exe and cmder `init.bat` respectivley.

```json
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [ "/k", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"],
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problum but it got fixed by following this steps

1. go to setting and search *json*
2. click on **launch** -(Edit in setting.json)
3. now replace the line "terminal.integrated.shell.windows":(*path as showing*) line to

   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [ "/k", "C:\cmder\vendor\init.bat"],
4. save the program. Done!