# npm install The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to set up a basic Azure Functions Local Environment by following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node#run-the-function-locally), however, after reaching the [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node#run-the-function-locally) and try to run it `F5` I get following error in the terminal.

```
> Executing task: npm install <
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I haven't even changed anything, and it's all just basic code and configurations.

My Node path `C:\Program Files\nodejs` is already added to `PATH` in environment variables.

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue by following the same documentation provided in the question.

1. Created a workspace folder for the azure function in my local environment : `C:\Users\surya\source\repos\suryanodejsazfunctionapp`
2. Open VS Code > Click on Azure function extension > Click on new project - It will ask you to choose the workspace path in which i have chosen the above path.
3. Selected Java Script Language > `HTTP trigger` template and the authorization level as `anonymous`
4. By default, some boiler plate code is created by VS code and executed using `F5` command
   [image]

NOTE :

1. Check Azure function core tools version using `func version` and node version using `node --version` (Download node 14 or 16 and AZ function core tools 3 or 4v)

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

For the above error, please check through this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777212/visual-studio-code-terminal-error-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label)

Comment: My issue got resolve by adding ` "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [ "/k", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"],` in `settings.json`